# Error messages while bootstrapping lmer regression coefficients in R

Tags: r

I have the following model:

```
res7=lmer(Residence_time~Species+Sex+(1|Chamber), data=ResidTimes, REML=FALSE)
```

Species and Sex are two-level factors. This model gives the following output:

```
    Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
    Formula: Residence_time ~ Species + Sex + (1 | Chamber)
       Data: ResidTimes

         AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
      2103.2   2124.0  -1046.6   2093.2      471 

    Scaled residuals: 
        Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
    -1.4434 -0.7568 -0.3249  0.7676  2.5752 

    Random effects:
     Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
     Chamber  (Intercept) 0.247    0.497   
     Residual             4.585    2.141   
    Number of obs: 476, groups:  Chamber, 27

    Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value
    (Intercept)     5.0674     0.1846  27.454
    Speciesrubrus  -1.0195     0.2180  -4.676
    Sexmale         0.3949     0.2021   1.954

    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) Spcsrb
    Speciesrbrs -0.457       
    Sexmale     -0.531  0.154
```

The residuals for this model are not normal, so I would like to bootstrap the parameter estimates with a parametric bootstrap. To do this I have done the following:

```
library(boot)
b_par7<-bootMer(x=res7,FUN=fixef,nsim=2000, use.u = FALSE, type="parametric")
```

However I get the following warning message:

```
    Warning messages:
    1: In optwrap(object@optinfo$optimizer, ff, x0, lower = lower, control = control$optCtrl,  :
      convergence code 3 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- a trust region step failed to reduce q
    2: In optwrap(object@optinfo$optimizer, ff, x0, lower = lower, control = control$optCtrl,  :
      convergence code 3 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- a trust region step failed to reduce q
```

Is there any way that I can fix this error, or do I need to run a lower number of bootstrap replicates?

Comment: Maybe try tweaking the optimizer. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmerperf.html

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @MattBarstead. I had no luck trying to change the optimizer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the optimizer failed k=2 times out of R=2000 attempts to re-fit your model for random subsamples of your data. No matter how one tweaks the optimizer it will still occasionally fail in difficult cases, especially since we would like to set R as large as we could afford to get more accurate statistics.

While we wait for better (more stable) optimizer to be developed, I suggest to mute these warnings

```
be.quiet <- capture.output(b_par7 <- bootMer(...), type="message")
```

and to use the remaining R-k=1998 re-samples to compute your bootstrap statistics with. Again, try if you could afford more re-samples, like R=2e4 by using multiple CPUs with

```
options(boot.parallel="multicore")
options(boot.ncpus=4)
```

P.S. To make sure boot.ci() will never crash, but always return either confidence interval or c(NA,NA), you could wrap it like this. R = the actual number of non-failed resamples.

```
tt <- tryCatch(boot::boot.ci(b_par7, index=i, type="perc")$percent[4:5], 
               error = function(e) c(NA,NA))
if( length(tt)<2 ) tt <- c(NA,NA)  # catch peculiar boot.ci error reported by "print"

c(R = sum(!is.na(b_par7$t[,i])), lower.CI = tt[1], upper.CI = tt[2])
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniil. When I get the confidence intervals for the parameter estimates using boot.ci(), will R ignore the 2 re samples that failed and use the remaining 1998 to obtain the confidence intervals?